# Filtering array by inner array value

Tags: javascript

I have an object which contains an array which looks like this:

```
{
    "media": [
        {
            "title": "Raiders of the Lost Ark",
            "year": "1981",
            "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjA0ODEzMTc1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODM2MjAxNA@@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,664,1000_AL_.jpg",
            "genre": ["action", "adventure"],
            "type": "movie"
        },
        {
            "title": "The Other Guys",
            "year": "2010",
            "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0NDQzNTA2Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzI2OTQzMw@@._V1_.jpg",
            "genre": ["action", "comedy", "crime"],
            "type": "movie"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a filter function which will return all the items with a certain genre.

Here's the filter I made but doesn't seem to return any values.

```
//pretend movies equals my parsed JSON file 
const Movies = json.media; 

const Filter = function(array, key, value){
    let i, j, filteredResults = [], item;

    for(i =  0, j = array.length; i<j; i++){
        item = array[i];
        if(typeof item[key] !== "undefined" && item[key] === value){
            filteredResults.push(item);
        }
    }

    return filteredResults;
}

console.log(Filter(Movies, "genre", "action"));
```

This returns no value but should return an array with the 2 movies in it?

Comment: `Movies.filter(m => m.genre.includes('action'))`

Comment: In your implementation: `item[key] === value` here you're comparing an array with a string.

Comment: Please study what JSON is and is not. This is not JSON. It is just a JavaScript object. Also, this is not about "sorting" it seems to be about "filtering". Finally, how is this related to ES6?

Comment: Wow that's a really nice implementation thanks @zekms

Comment: To solve your problem, you could "debug" it, by stepping through it line by line with the debugger. Focus on the line containing the `if`. Break on that line, and examine the variables `item[key]` and `value` and you should be able to see why the condition is not being met.

Comment: Apologies @torazaburo I  didn't think I was wrong by calling it JSON my mistake. Oh awesome I'll try that, learn some better ways to debug, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. It is not a *better way to debug*, it is **the** way to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the filter method

```
var medias = [
    {
        "title": "Raiders of the Lost Ark",
        "year": "1981",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjA0ODEzMTc1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODM2MjAxNA@@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,664,1000_AL_.jpg",
        "genre": ["action", "adventure"],
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Other Guys",
        "year": "2010",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0NDQzNTA2Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzI2OTQzMw@@._V1_.jpg",
        "genre": ["action", "comedy", "crime"],
        "type": "movie"
    }
]
sortedMedias = medias.filter(elem => elem.genre.indexOf("crime")!=-1);
console.log(sortedMedias); //  [ { title: 'The Other Guys',
                           //      year: '2010',
                           //      poster: 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0NDQzNTA2Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzI2OTQzMw@@._V1_.jpg',
                           //      genre: [ 'action', 'comedy', 'crime' ],
                           //      type: 'movie' } ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. There is just one point to be changed :

- The 'genre' property is itself an array so the 'indexOf' the 'action'
  parameter must be checked

  ```
  const Filter = function(obj, key, value) {
      let i, j, filteredResults = [], item;

      // The media property is the array in which we want to search 
      let array = obj.media;

      for(i =  0, j = array.length; i < j; i++){
          item = array[i];

          // the genre property is itself an array
          // so we'll need to find the 'indexOf' the item
          // rather than comparing directly

          if(typeof item[key] !== "undefined" && item[key].indexOf(value) !== -1){
              filteredResults.push(item);
          }
      }

      return filteredResults;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if(_.contains(item[key], value)){
  filteredResults.push(item);
}
```

instead of

```
if(typeof item[key] !== "undefined" && item[key] === value){
  filteredResults.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Not tagged Underscore, please provide native solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep it simple. I maybe something like this would suit you

```
function movieFilter (where, field, search) {
  if (typeof search !== "string") { search = search.toString()}; //for example if you want to search by the year, and you provide integer search number
  return where.filter(item => {
    return item[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  })
}
```

Here is a playground example of this function
https://jsbin.com/tepifa/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a generic filter function, you should consider few cases:

- Strict Equality (===)
- Loose Equality (==)
- partOf

```js
var d = {
  "media": [{
    "title": "Raiders of the Lost Ark",
    "year": "1981",
    "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjA0ODEzMTc1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODM2MjAxNA@@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,664,1000_AL_.jpg",
    "genre": ["action", "adventure"],
    "type": "movie"
  }, {
    "title": "The Other Guys",
    "year": "2010",
    "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTc0NDQzNTA2Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzI2OTQzMw@@._V1_.jpg",
    "genre": ["action", "comedy", "crime"],
    "type": "movie"
  }]
}
var _g = "action";
function filter(array, key, value, operation) {
  return array.filter(x=>{
    switch(operation){
      case "contains": return x[key].indexOf(value)>-1;
      case "ignoreType": return x[key] == value;
      default: return x[key] === value;
    }
  })
}
console.log(filter(d.media, "genre", "action", "contains"))
console.log(filter(d.media, "year", 2010))
console.log(filter(d.media, "year", 2010, "ignoreType"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    item[key].forEach(function(oneDoc){

        if(oneDoc == value){
            filteredResults.push(item);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

First Need to find index of value. If the index is not -1 that means value is persent in array.

```
for(i =  0, j = array.length; i<j; i++){
    item = array[i];
    if(typeof item[key] !== "undefined" && item[key].indexOf(value) !==    -1 ){
        filteredResults.push(item);
    }
}
```